# How to replace part of an input value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I've been trying to figure out a way to replace part of a string in an *input* value, but haven't been able to get it working.

The *input field* looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="20,54,26,99" name="ids" />
```

I've tried:

```
$('input[name=ids]').val().replace("54,","");
```

and

```
var replit = $('input[name=ids]').val();
replit.replace("54,","");
$('input[name=ids]').val(replit);
```

but neither worked?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('input[name=ids]').val(function(index, value) {
   return value.replace('54,', '');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried this

```
$('#title').val($('#title').val().replace("54,",""))
```

and it worked so i assume that it's the way you call the element "$('input[name=ids]')", why don't you try using an id selector?

```
$('#ids')
```

Comment: the `#` in the jquery selector is for the 'id' attribute... won't select an element with a name of 'ids'...

Comment: @Damien-at-SF Maybe they've used <= IE8's `getElementById()` too much :D

Comment: forget it, it have nothing to do with the selector

Comment: @alex hahaha i forget there is a pre IE8 :P sometimes i forget what i did before jquery :P

Comment: i was just saying that he could try assigning an id attribute to his input and then use it as selector, not using the name as id...

Comment: @raphael, aaaaah that makes sense now :)

Comment: jej however that was not the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

try

```
replit = replit.replace("54,","");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var replit = $('input[name=ids]').val().replace("54,","");
$('input[name=ids]').val(replit);
```

hope that helps :)

EDIT: if you want a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/XQQC2/

:)

Answer (score 1):

I used this method, however I also included a line of code that replaces part of a string.

```
var matval = document.getElementById("MaterialNumber").value;

var matNum = matval.replace("P", "");

document.getElementById("MaterialNumber").value = "";

document.getElementById("MaterialNumber").value = matNum;
```

Generally I would not have cleared out the field before putting in the new string, but it did not work like that in this case, This might have been caused by the input method being a barcode scanner and set into a function based on a keypress of that said barcode scanner.

Comment: Generally I would not have cleared out the field before putting in the new string, but it did not work like that in this case, This might have been caused by the input method being a barcode scanner and set into a function based on a keypress of that said barcode scanner.