# Remove/delete part of hidden field value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hidden-field

I am trying to build a form where users can add a course using select boxes.

When a course is added, it creates a new table row displaying the course to the user and also adds the course prefix and number (e.g. MATH120) to a hidden form field value. Finally, it adds a delete button.

The delete button should remove the table row AND the hidden input value that corresponds to the course being deleted.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MtJF2/10/

My script is deleting the row just fine, but its not removing the input value correctly. It's not throwing any errors. Sometimes I've noticed that it will delete the zero in the correct value (e.g. MATH120, becomes MATH12,). Any ideas what might be causing this?

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCourse($course){
    $('#' + $course).remove();
    $course = $course + ','
    alert($course);
    $('#required-courses').val(function($course, value) {
   return value.replace($course, '');
});
}
</script>
<table width="80%" align="center">
    <tr id="add-required-course">
        <td><input type="button" value="+ Add a Required Course" class="MC-big-button" onclick="$('#course-menu').slideToggle()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<input type="hidden" id="required-courses" name="required-courses" value="null" />
<table id="course-menu" width="80%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Select the course prefix:</td>
        <td><select id="1" name="course-prefix">
                <option value="MATH">MATH</option>
                <option value="BIOL">BIOL</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select the course number:</td>
        <td><select id="2" name="course-num">
            <option value="101">101</option>
            <option value="120">120</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="button" value="Add this course" class="MC-big-button" id="save-course" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("save-course").onclick = buildCourse;

function buildCourse() {
    var $coursePrefix = ($('#1').val());
    var $courseNum = ($('#2').val());
    var $course = $coursePrefix + $courseNum;
    var $HTMLoutput = '<tr id="' + $course + '"><td>' + $course + '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteCourse(\'' + $course + '\')" /></td></tr>';
    var $VALUEoutput = ($('#required-courses').val());
    if ($VALUEoutput == 'null') {
        $VALUEoutput = $course + ',';
    }
    else {
         $VALUEoutput = $VALUEoutput + $course + ',';
    }
    $('#course-menu').slideToggle();
    $('#add-required-course').before($HTMLoutput);
    $('#required-courses').val($VALUEoutput);    
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505718/how-to-replace-part-of-an-input-value-in-jquery) to be helpful, but I think my implementation is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing `$course` with a new value in the delete function at

```
$('#required-courses').val(function($course, value) { 
// here it gets a new value which is wrong
```

Use it like this

```
function deleteCourse($course){

    $('#' + $course).remove();
    $course = $course + ','
    alert($course);

    $('#required-courses').val(function(_, value) {
            return value.replace($course, '');
    });
}
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. I thought I was passing the $course variable into that function and didn't realize I was actually replacing it. Doh!